# How can I find and change an entry in fixed length record without matching fields that contain the same characters? Ex. "Smith" is true in Smithers

Tags: python, regex

I need to find (F)irstname (L)astname in the record and change the (B)irthday for that record. The input that gets me is when the input is "Adam" "Smith" as it is found in "Adam Smith" and  Adam Smithers and both birthdates get changed. I have tried using indexing to isolate the last name and compare it to the value of "L" but it never registered as true.

```
if re.search(F, recordLine):
   lastName = recordLine[start+16:start+32]
   if L == lastName:
     recordLine = record[start:start + recordLength - 8]+ B
```

I've tried substituting this code for the if statement in the code I wrote below below in an attempt to fix the issue but it never returns True.

```
recordLength = 40
start = 0
recordList = []

file1 = open(P, 'r')
record = file1.read()
file1.close()
file1 = open(P, 'w')
while( (len(record) - start) >= recordLength):

  recordLine = record[start:start + recordLength]
  recordList.append(recordLine)
  if re.search(F, recordLine) and re.search(L, recordLine):    
    recordLine = record[start:start + recordLength - 8]+ B     
  file1.write(recordLine)
  start+= recordLength  
file1.close()
```

```
Your output:
Adam            Smith           11111900* 
Theodore        Anderson        03201990 
Monty           Biscuit-Barrel  10181980 
Adam            Smithers        11111900* 
Ruthy           Anderson        06062010
Expected output:
Adam            Smith           11111900*
Theodore        Anderson        03201990
Monty           Biscuit-Barrel  10181980
Adam            Smithers        10101960
Ruthy           Anderson        06062010
```

The indicated (B)irtdates are the ones that changed. Codio the program we are using seems to run the code with different variables to make sure it functions so it's hard to know exactly what it is. But my issue comes when F=Adam and L= Smith

Comment: Use this pseudo-regex `(?m)^(.{LastLenField})(.{FirstLenField})(.{BirthdayLenField})` then you have the fields. Or if need to be specific `(?m)^(?=Smith\b)(.{LastLenField})(?=\bAdam\b)(.{FirstLenField})(.{BirthdayLenField})`

Answer (score 0):

You need regular expressions.

You're already using `re` to search, so you're halfway there.

Essentially, regular expressions allow you to search for a **pattern** of letters, rather than the letters themselves - in your case, you want to search for a phrase that matches "Smith" and then stops, with no more letters.

In regular expressions, `$` is the character that means "and no more characters" - it matches the end of a string. "Smith$" would match the word "Smith" but not "Smithers" or "Smithson".

Have a look at the [re documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) and also [regexr](http://regexr.com).

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try it, now working on figuring out how to use $ with a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have the First name and last name so you can make a pattern like this `r'Adam\s+Smith\s+'`, but let say that the first name can have multiple Words.

To handle this we know that the `length` of first name is `16`, last name is `16`, birthday is `8`, we can extract this information by slicing or by regular expression:

```py
import re

FIRST_NAME = 'Adam'
LAST_NAME = 'Smith'
P = 'data.txt'
B = '11111900'

# if every record is in one line do this is better
with open(P, 'r') as readable_file1:
    records = readable_file1.readlines()


with open(P, 'w') as writable_file1:
    for record in records:
        # you can do by slicing like you did
        info = re.search('(.{16})(.{16})(.{8})', record)
        if info:
            first_name, last_name, birthday = info.groups()
            if first_name.strip() == FIRST_NAME and last_name.strip() == LAST_NAME:
                print('Record to update: ', record)
                record = record[:32] + B + '\n'
        writable_file1.write(record)
```